# Activeadmin_addons gem tagging is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am trying implement activeadmin_addons gem from https://github.com/halilim/activeadmin_addons . Some of it's features are working. Autocomplete is working. I was following their **Select2** tags. 
The documentation says replace the `:select` with `:tags`.

This is my code:

```
 f.input :user_id, as: :tags, collection: User.active.pluck(:email, :id), include_blank: 'Select User', label: 'Requester'.html_safe
```

Once I replaced the `:select` with `:tags`. It went back to how it was before. No autocomplete nothing. Once restored `:select` again autocomplete started working. What is wrong here?

Comment: Hi, check whether the generator added necessary changes. https://github.com/halilim/activeadmin_addons/blob/master/docs/install_generator.md

Comment: That generator didn't work so I added them manually to respective files. Autocomplete is working but `:tags` is not working.

Comment: I think the issue is related with this PR https://github.com/platanus/activeadmin_addons/pull/131